# How to pick from several collections in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have several functions that plot a various collections into axis `ax`:

```
def my_scatter(ax, ...):
    pc = ax.scatter(...)

def plot(ax, ...):
    lc = mpl.collections.LineCollection(...)
    ax.add_collection(lc)
```

Now, I'd like to add a picker to each of them, so that finally for each collection a function plus index of picked collection member gets called. Pseudo-coded this would implement something in the following sense:

```
def example_pick_fct1(idx):
   ...

def example_pick_fct2(idx):
   ...

def my_scatter(ax, pickfct, ...):
    pc = ax.scatter(...)
    pc.add_pickfct(pickfct)

def my_lines(ax, pickfct, ...):
    lc = mpl.collections.LineCollection(...)
    ax.add_collection(lc)
    lc.add_pickfct(pickfct)

my_scatter(ax, example_pick_fct1, ...)
my_scatter(ax, example_pick_fct2, ...)
my_lines(ax, example_pick_fct2, ...)
```

I had a close look into the documentation, but currently I do not see a good strategy on how to implement it. **Can anyone give some advice?** (Once more, the example is really pseudo-code and I'm completely open for any nice solution with the same functionality.)

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudocode is actually fine. It is just not possible to add a pickerfunction directly to the artist. Instead, you may apply a global picker which then selects which function to call. This can be controlled by previously adding the maps (artist -> function) to a commonly used dictionary. Depending which artists triggers the event, the respective function may be called.

Here is a code that does it, closely following your example code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import colorConverter
import numpy as np


a1 = np.random.rand(16,2)
a2 = np.random.rand(16,2)
a3 = np.random.rand(5,6,2)

# Create a pickermap dictionary that stores 
# which function should be called for which artist
pickermap = {}
def add_to_picker_map(artist, func):
    if func != None:
        pickermap.update({artist:func})


def example_pick_fct1(event):
   print "You clicked example_pick_fct1\n\ton", event.artist

def example_pick_fct2(event):
   print "You clicked example_pick_fct2\n\ton", event.artist

def my_scatter(ax, pickfct=None):
    pc = ax.scatter(a2[:,0], a2[:,1], picker=5)
    # add the artist to the pickermap
    add_to_picker_map(pc, pickfct)

def my_lines(ax, pickfct=None):
    lc = matplotlib.collections.LineCollection(a3, picker=5, colors=[colorConverter.to_rgba(i) for i in 'bgrcmyk'])
    ax.add_collection(lc)
    # add the artist to the pickermap
    add_to_picker_map(lc, pickfct)

def onpick(event):
    # if the artist that triggered the event is in the pickermap dictionary
    # call the function associated with that artist
    if event.artist in pickermap:
        pickermap[event.artist](event)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
my_scatter(ax, example_pick_fct1)
# to register the same artist to two picker functions may not make too much sense, but I leave it here as you were asking for it
my_scatter(ax, example_pick_fct2) 
my_lines  (ax, example_pick_fct1)

#register the event handler
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```